# Calculating Euler angle transformations for a vector in 3D space

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script to do the following...

Assume we have an empty 3D matrix of points on axes X,Y,Z.  On this matrix we have several unique vectors which are described by a series of X,Y,Z points and a unique identifier integer.

1. for each unique vector, calculate the vector’s directionality.
2. calculate what angular transformations need to be made to a known vector which is parallel to the Z axis such that it would become parallel to the calculated vector of the unique vector from step 1.  These angular transformations should be expressed together as the rotation, tilt, and psi angles (in degrees).

The user provides an input text file containing 4 columns.  The first column is the unique vector identifier number, and columns 2,3,4 represent X,Y,Z coordinates within the matrix.  The output file should be identical to the input file except it will also include 3 new columns, the calculated rotation, tilt, and psi angles calculated in step 2 above.

I have so far the code below.  But when I run the script I am getting an index out of range error.   Some googling all I can guess is that I may be calculating the reference vector (aligned with Z axis) and it's giving a value of zero.  Not sure

```
import numpy as np
import math

def calculate_vector_directionality(x, y, z):
  """Calculates the directionality of a vector in 3D space.

  Args:
    x: The X coordinate of the vector.
    y: The Y coordinate of the vector.
    z: The Z coordinate of the vector.

  Returns:
    The directionality of the vector, in degrees.
  """

  directionality = math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / math.pi
  if directionality < 0:
    directionality += 360

  return directionality

def calculate_angular_transformations(vector, z_axis):
  """Calculates the angular transformations needed to make a vector parallel to the Z axis.

  Args:
    vector: The vector to transform.
    z_axis: The Z axis vector.

  Returns:
    The rotation, tilt, and psi angles, in degrees.
  """

  rotation = math.acos(np.dot(vector, z_axis)) * 180 / math.pi
  tilt = math.atan2(vector[1], vector[0]) * 180 / math.pi
  psi = math.atan2(vector[2], np.sqrt(vector[0]**2 + vector[1]**2)) * 180 / math.pi

  return rotation, tilt, psi

def main():
  """The main function of the script."""

  input_file = open("input.txt", "r")
  output_file = open("output.txt", "w")

  for line in input_file:
    line_data = line.split()
    line_id = int(line_data[0])
    x = float(line_data[1])
    y = float(line_data[2])
    z = float(line_data[3])

    vector = np.array([x, y, z])
    z_axis = np.array([0, 0, 1])

    directionality = calculate_vector_directionality(x, y, z)
    rotation, tilt, psi = calculate_angular_transformations(vector, z_axis)

    output_file.write("%d,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f\n" % (line_id, directionality, rotation, tilt, psi))

  input_file.close()
  output_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, so I'd suggest

```py
print(input_file.readlines())
```

and check that you don't have empty lines (`'\n'`) or missing values.